# Bash while loop, how to read input until a condition is false

Tags: bash

I keep getting a run time error. I'm running this in a terminal on OSX. The error is,

```
test.sh: line 15: while[!false]: command not found
test.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
test.sh: line 16: `do'
```

I just can't figure where I've got wrong syntactically as I'm new to writing bash scripts.

```
ipa build &
TASK_PID=$!
sleep 5
kill $TASK_PID

finished=false
declare -a schemes

echo "*****************************************************************************************"
echo "| View the list of available build configs above."
echo "| Enter the name of the build you want,one at a time."
echo "| Type \"done\" to finish entering scheme names"
echo "*****************************************************************************************"

while[!${finished}]
do
read input
  if[$input == "done"]
  then
      finished=true
  else
  schemes=("${schemes[@]}" $input)
  echo ${schemes[0]}
  fi
done

echo "Do you want a verbose build? (y/n)"
read verbose


echo "Building your selected schemes....."
ipa build -s ${schemes[0]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give space around brackets in test conditions

```
while [ ! ${finished} ]
```

&

```
if [ $input = "done" ]
```

Comment: `finished` is a string; the test will supply the same result whether that string's value is "true" or "false". Syntax is not the entire problem.

Answer (score 16):

`true` and `false` are not boolean keywords in `bash`; they are simply strings (and the names of commands; more on that in a moment). Even if you fix your syntax by supplying whitespace where necessary:

```
while ! [ "${finished}" ]; do
    ...
done
```

this loop will never run. Why? Whether `finished` has the value `true` or `false`, it is simply a non-empty string. This code will run the `[` command (yes, it's a command, not syntax) and succeed because its argument is a non-empty string. The `!` negates it, so that the condition for the `while` loop then *always* fails.

The most direct fix is to explicitly compare `$finished` to the string "true".

```
while [ "$finished" != "true" ]; do
   ...
done
```

---

I mentioned that `true` and `false` are also commands: `true` always succeeds, and `false` always fails. Usually, you do not want to do what I am about to suggest, but here it's OK because `true` and `false` are about as simple a pair of commands as you can imagine.

```
finished=false
while ! $finished; do
    ...
    # At some point
    finished=true
done
```

Here, we are letting `$finished` expand to the name of a command, which then executes and has its exit status negated by the `!`. As long as `finished=false`, the negated exit status is always 0 and the while loop will continue to run. Once you change the value of `finished`, the negated exit status will be 1 and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

list='Foo Bar Baz Quux Xyzzy QUIT'

select item in $list; do
    case $item in
    QUIT)
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo "You picked '$item'!"
        ;;
    esac
done
```